# MySQL Union - NULL as var?

Tags: mysql, union

Check out this query example:

```
(SELECT fistName, middleName, lastName
FROM a)
UNION
(SELECT fistName, NULL as middleName, lastName
FROM b)
```

Is that going to work properly?  Table b has no middle name column at all...  I figured if that doesn't function right, I could always try this:

```
'' as middlename
```

Thanks....

Comment: Although there's already an answer, keep in mind that `SELECT` queries generally have no side effects and the easiest way to see if it works is to try it.

Comment: @MichaelMior Good point, thanks Mike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it will work. Also, you do not need to use `as middleName`

```
(SELECT fistName, middleName, lastName
FROM a)
UNION
(SELECT fistName, NULL, lastName
FROM b)
```